# Left join in MySQL 8.0 is much slower than in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table named `mkt_coupon_item`

in 5.6 :

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `mkt_coupon_item` (
  `rec_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ps_id` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `goods_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rec_id`),
  KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  KEY `ps_id` (`ps_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_goods_id` (`goods_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24596468 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

in 8.0:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mkt_coupon_item` (
  `rec_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ps_id` int NOT NULL,
  `goods_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rec_id`),
  KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  KEY `ps_id` (`ps_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_goods_id` (`goods_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17693330 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The two tables have the almost same data(with little difference), witch is about 14,000,000 rows of record.

**Executing the SQL statement below（get the  difference of `item_number` by two ps_ids）**:

```sql
SELECT
        a.rec_id,
        a.item_number 
FROM
        mkt_coupon_item AS a
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ps_id, item_number FROM mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6446 ) AS c ON c.item_number = a.item_number 
WHERE
        a.ps_id = 6463
        AND c.ps_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY
        a.rec_id;
```

**It takes about 2 seconds in MySQL 5.6， but 35 seconds in MySQL 8.0**

Explain in MySQL 5.6:

```
+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                |
+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY   | a              | ref  | ps_id        | ps_id       | 4       | const                   | 58212 | Using where          |
|  1 | PRIMARY   | <derived2>      | ref  | <auto_key1>  | <auto_key1> | 48      | a.item_number |    10 | Using where; Not exists |
|  2 | DERIVED   | mkt_coupon_item | ref  | ps_id        | ps_id       | 4       | const                   | 62360 | NULL                 |
+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+
```

Explain in 8.0:

```
+----+------------+----------------+----------+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key         | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+------------+----------------+----------+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE     | a              | NULL     | ref  | ps_id           | ps_id       | 4       | const                   | 56434 | 100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE     | mkt_coupon_item | NULL     | ref  | item_number,ps_id | item_number | 63      | a.item_number |    78 |  10.00 | Using where |
+----+------------+----------------+----------+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+-------+--------+-------------+

mysql> explain format=tree SELECT
        a.rec_id,
        a.item_number 
FROM
        mkt_coupon_item AS a
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ps_id, item_number FROM mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6446 ) AS c ON c.item_number = a.item_number 
WHERE
        a.ps_id = 6463
        AND c.ps_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY
        a.rec_id;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| -> Filter: (mkt_coupon_item.ps_id is null)  (cost=4848182.12 rows=440673)
    -> Nested loop left join  (cost=4848182.12 rows=440673)
        -> Index lookup on a using ps_id (ps_id=6463)  (cost=61302.33 rows=56434)
        -> Filter: (mkt_coupon_item.ps_id = 6446)  (cost=77.01 rows=8)
            -> Index lookup on mkt_coupon_item using item_number (item_number=a.item_number)  (cost=77.01 rows=78)
 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Seems the join step is much slower by this sentence:  Nested loop left join  (cost=4848182.12 rows=440673)**

Info about rows number with ps_id 6446/6463 :

In MySQL 5.6:

```
mysql> select count(*) from mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6446;
+---------+
| count(*) |
+---------+
|   30159 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.59 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6463;
+---------+
| count(*) |
+---------+
|   30163 |
+---------+
1 row in set (1.12 sec)
```

In MySQL 8.0:

```
mysql> select count(*) from mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6446;
+---------+
| count(*) |
+---------+
|   30159 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.55 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from mkt_coupon_item WHERE ps_id = 6463;
+---------+
| count(*) |
+---------+
|   30163 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.52 sec)
```

I have google for two days but with no lucky, any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily even see the point of left joining to a subquery.  Instead, I suggests using exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT a.rec_id, a.item_number 
FROM mkt_coupon_item a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mkt_coupon_item c
    WHERE c.item_number = a.item_number AND
          c.ps_id = 6446
) AND a.ps_id = 6463
ORDER BY a.rec_id;
```

Adding one of the following two indices should help this query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON mkt_coupon_item (item_number, ps_id);
```

Or

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON mkt_coupon_item (ps_id, item_number);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know it is ok by using `not exists` or `not in`(I'v tested they are more faster in mysql 8.0 with this example) , but people  always say that `left join` , `not exists`, `not in` are all ok to do the thing, what i wonder is why left join is so slow in MySQL 8.0 ( it's ok in MySQL 5.6).